# Get all documents from Firestore Database

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently making a Flutter app for practice, similar to a Twitter clone app. However, I have a problem when I try to get all documents from Firestore Database.
I use UID as document id and want to see all user's posts.
But only the posts of the currently logged in user are displayed.

In this case, how can I get all the documents?

I want to display posts by user [B1vq9.........] and posts by [QVf5.........].

[image]

I tried:

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final User? user = auth.currentUser;
final uid = user!.uid;

FirebaseFirestore.collection('post').doc(uid).collection('talk').snapshots();
```

However, this code can only display posts from the currently logged in user.

`collection('talk')` is a subcollection.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtJsj.png)

Answer (score 3):

If you need all the posts from `posts`'s collection you only need

```
FirebaseFirestore.collection('post').snapshots()
```

If you append `.doc(uid).collection('talk')` then this will fetch all the documents inside `{uid}/talk`.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your advice and I tried it.
But this code above [FirebaseFirestore.collection('post').snapshots()]couldn't get all user's posts.
I also tried [FirebaseFirestore.collection('post').doc(uid).collection('talk').snapshots()] which can access only current logged in user's post.

Comment: You mean to say each user's post is inside post/{uid}/talk path?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply.
Yes each user's post is inside of post/{uid}/talk.

Comment: if that's the case, you might have to do a loop on FirebaseFirestore.collection('post') for each document and get the documents inside 'talk' collection. I would suggest put the posts inside the 'posts' collection directly and add a 'createdBy' field with the user id of the respective user.